# Delete tree leaf with specific Int in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tree, functional-programming, int

I have the defined Type: **data Tree = Node Tree Tree | Leaf Int | NIL**. I want create a method **delete :: Tree -> Int -> Tree** which removes all Leaf's with the specific Int given in the second parameter.

Comment: Even if you're new to Haskell you should be able to implement at least some base case, e.g. `delete (Leaf n) n' =`.

Comment: The main problem is, i dont know how I can delete a Leaf from the Tree.

Comment: The only thing i know is the Type: **data Tree = Node Tree Tree | Leaf Int | NIL**. But I'm sure that the tree is a binary Tree with Int Values on the Leaves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your tree doesn't have any particular structure, you can do

```
delete NIL _ = NIL
delete (Leaf i) int | i == int = NIL
                    | otherwise = Leaf i
delete (Node left right) int = Node (delete left int) (delete right int)
```

### Why?

`delete NIL _ = NIL` because we have to deal with all cases, even the empty trees at the ends. The `_` stands for any value that we don't care about.

```
delete (Leaf i) int | i == int = NIL
                    | otherwise = Leaf i
```

because we need to first check `| i== int` to see whether we want to delete the node. If we do, we replace it with the empty three, `NIL`. Otherwise, we leave it alone.

`delete (Node left right) int = Node (delete left int) (delete right int)` because if we're at a node, we need to delete the `int` from both `left` and `right` subtrees.

### Aren't you going to end up with a whole load of `NIL`s?

Yes, I suppose that could happen. You could clear up with

```
prune (Node  NIL      NIL    ) = NIL
prune (Node (Leaf i)  NIL    ) = Leaf i 
prune (Node  NIL     (Leaf i)) = Leaf i 
prune (Node (Leaf i) (Leaf j)) = Node (Leaf i) (Leaf j)
prune (Node  left     right  ) = prune (Node (prune left) (prune right))
prune t = t
```

The first three lines get rid of a `NIL` on the left, right or both, and the fourth leaves two leaves alone.

The fifth line only gets called when one of the left or right subtrees of this node is itself a node. Why `prune` three times? Maybe when you `prune left` and `prune right` one or more of them ends up `NIL`.

The `prune t = t` deals with both `NIL` and `Leaf i` in one neat pattern match.

Comment: Wow thats the best answer I have ever seen. I want give more likes!

Comment: One thing that is important to understand is that you're actually not deleting anything. Instead you're creating a copy of the tree, but with those nodes removed.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest some improvements to AndrewC's answer. While his solution is absolutely correct, it has some potential performance issue.

The issue is: both `delete` and `prune` functions create a new copy of the whole tree on every call. That happens regardless of whether an element was actually deleted.

The worst case scenario is deleting a non-existing element.

Let's say we have a really big tree that holds 1M of integers. Since integers are stored in leaves only, the whole tree contains at least 2M-1 of nodes. (Or even more if the tree was not pruned yet thus contains NIL nodes).

When we try to delete a non-existing element from such a huge tree, our `delete` function will do absolutely nothing but duplicating all 2M of nodes. (And `prune` will duplicate them again!)

Deleting an existing element is just a tiny bit better. At this case, `delete` removes one leaf, updates it's parent and duplicates the rest of the tree. `prune` will probably remove a few more nodes but will duplicate the rest.

### Why does that happen?

There are two places where duplication happens.

This line creates a new tree that is completely identical to the argument:

```
delete (Leaf i) int | ...
                    | otherwise = Leaf i
```

Also, this line creates a new tree even if the element is not present in both left and right branches:

```
delete (Node left right) int = Node (delete left int) (delete right int)
```

### Is it possible to avoid unnecessary duplication?

Yes, of course. We just need to return the argument if we do not modify it.

Here is my version:

```
delete t i = fst $ delete' t i
  where delete' NIL _ = (NIL, True)
        delete' t@(Leaf i) int | i == int = (NIL, False)
                               | otherwise = (t, True)
        delete' t@(Node left right) int =
            let (left', unchangedLeft) = delete' left int
                (right', unchangedRight) = delete' right int
            in
              if unchangedLeft && unchangedRight
                then (t, True)
                else (Node left' right', False)
```

As you can see, I use a helper function `delete'` that returns a pair of (Tree, Bool) where second element is True if the tree was not changed, and False otherwise.

This function builds a new tree that shares most of the nodes with the original one. It only changes nodes on the path from root to the deleted element.

### What about `prune` ?

The version above does not delete `NIL` elements. As AndrewC noted, after performing multiple deletes we may have a tree with a lot of `NIL`s. To address this issue, we can either modify `prune` in the similar way, or we can merely integrate it into the `delete`:

```
delete t i = fst $ delete'' t i
  where delete'' NIL _ = (NIL, True)
        delete'' t@(Leaf i) int | i == int = (NIL, False)
                                | otherwise = (t, True)
        delete'' t@(Node left right) int =
            let (left', unchangedLeft) = delete'' left int
                (right', unchangedRight) = delete'' right int
            in
              if unchangedLeft && unchangedRight
                then (t, True)
                else (newNode left' right', False)

        newNode NIL r = r
        newNode l NIL = l
        newNode l r = Node l r
```